# Analyze Solution for Code Clones command is absent in VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I can't find this command in `ANALYZE` menu. Also there is no `Find matching clones in solution` in context menu.

[image]

I have tried `TOOLS`>`CUSTOMIZE`>`COMMANDS` but without success. There is no such command.
I'm using `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Analyse solution for Code Clones" is only available in Ultimate and Premium editions of Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Yeah, very sad.  There are other tools like Resharper and CodeRush that have features/add-ons to detect duplicate code...

Comment: Yes, see http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare and expand the "Integrated Development Environment" item in the bottom table. You will see you need at least Premium, as Peter says

Comment: @PaulSmith "Analyse solution for Code Clones" only appears for certain projects.  Which types of projects have you looked?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, You're right; this was a Web Site project (ugh), and it appears they omitted the feature there. Shame it doesn't scan blocks under 10 lines long, too.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I am using visual studio 2013 community version. I need this tools for code analysis. Have you any idea, how do i?

Answer (score 0):

its depend on solution type 
for website this options disappear
convert your website to web application for detection clone code